# Can't change params in Rmd documents

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

As explained on [this site](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html) it is possible to define parameters in the YAML header of a Rmarkdown file and the default values specified there can be overwritten with `rmarkdown::render("foo.Rmd", params = list(param1 = "bar")`. However when I try this I get the following error:

**params object already exists in knit environment so can't be overwritten by render params**

Here is a minimal reproducible Rmd document. Let's say the file name is `test.Rmd`.

```
---
title: "Test"
output: pdf_document
params:
  name: Andreas
---

Hello, my name is `r params$name`.
```

When I now try `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", params = list(name = "Jordan")` it stops with the error written above.

This is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.11      rmarkdown_0.7.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0      XML_3.98-1.3     digest_0.6.8     MASS_7.3-40     grid_3.2.1      
 [6] plyr_1.8.3       gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.2.5     ggplot2_1.0.1   
[11] stringi_0.5-5    reshape2_1.4.1   jwiDlst_0.1.1    proto_0.3-10     tools_3.2.1     
[16] stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2    yaml_2.1.13      parallel_3.2.1   colorspace_1.2-6
[21] htmltools_0.2.6
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: your code works well for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error message indicates you have already got an object named `params` in your current workspace, and you should remove it (`rm(params)`) before calling `rmarkdown::render()`. Use `ls()` to double check the objects in the current environment.

Comment: Thanks! I was interpreting "knit environment" to be "the new session created for knitting" rather than the environment from which I called the render function. Helpful to remember when testing Rmd code interactively!

Answer (score 24):

Alternatively - knit the document in a new environment by including the option `envir = new.env()`:

```
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", params = list(name = "Jordan"), envir = new.env() )
```

I like to do this in any case to make sure the rmarkdown report only uses objects that were explicitly defined as part of its own code.