# Mail merge using R Markdown for loop

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to do a mail merge through R to produce multiple letters with individualised addresses. 
All of the address details are captured in a separate data frame. I have based this code off here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/mail-merge-with-rmarkdown/ .

There are currently three parts to the code that is apart of this process:

1. a dataframe containing names and mail address details.
2. An R markdown  file with the contents of a letter that I am trying to produce for everyone person listed in the dataframe.
3. A script that loops through the dataframe and produces an R markdown document for each person.

To condense it all, my dataframe `Address` looks like this:

````
```
Name      Address            Suburb    Postcode
Bob       1 Brown  St        Willeton  5234 
John      17A Berkley Loop   East City 2345 
Jenny     6 Frangipani Rd    Central   5423
```
````

The relevant R Markdown code chunk looks like this:

````
```
```{r, echo=FALSE}
#Load data
load("Address.Rdata")

  Name[i]<-Address$Name[i] 
  Addr[i]<-Address$Address[i]
  Suburb[i]<-Address$Suburb[i]
  Postcode[i]<-Address$Postcode[i]   
```

```
`r Name`  
`r Addr`  
`r Suburb`  
`r Postcode`  
```
````

and finally, the script that loops through the R Markdown document to create letters for each person in the dataframe looks like this:

````
```
#Import libraries 
library(knitr) 
library(markdown)

#BusName
load("Address.RData")


#Loop to read each business name
for (i in 1:nrow(Address)){
  rmarkdown::render(input = "Address-report.Rmd",
                    output_format = "word_document",
                    output_file = paste(Address$Name[i], ".doc", sep=''),
                    output_dir = "H:/...folders/stuff/")

}
```
````

When I run my version of it, multiple documents are produced for each person (each is titled correctly), but the address details in the contents of the letters are overwriting with each iteration of the loop. So when the loop has finished running, all of the letters produced have the same contact details of the person in the last row of the data frame.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can point out where I am going wrong, thanks!

Comment: The iteration variable `i` is not being passed from your final script to each RMarkdown document.  You could try passing it through by adding `params = list(i = i)` to `rmarkdown::render`.  See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024013/cant-change-params-in-rmd-documents).